# How can I update my OS X 10.5.8?

Tags: macos, upgrade

This is the first time I've ever had a computer that didn't play out on me before it needed an upgrade and now I'm lost. This is also my first Mac laptop, and I am running OS X 10.5.8 (Yes, I realize it's old…I had it put up for a while)

Can someone tell me the next step or steps that I can take to do an upgrade?  I have no clue which animal I'm running or what I need to go to. I'm noticing more and more sites/actions are telling me that they are not compatible because my system is no longer up to date.

Comment: First lets find out about the animal, click on the apple in top left corner and then about this Mac

Comment: You are running Leopard; 10.5 is Leopard, 10.6 is Snow Leopard. (@Buscar the OS X version was provided in the question)

Answer (score 5):

See here: http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/

TL;DR: [buy a DVD](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) to update to Snow Leopard and then update it to Mavericks (if your hardware supports it).

Answer (score 2):

Before you upgrade you should deeply consider the question "why upgrade?"

Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard is a mature and stable operating system that has some very interesting and particular features that are not available in most of the more recent OS X releases, including the [Classic Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Classic) and [a transparent emulation layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29) that both allow you to run (possibly expensive or irreplacible) software that ran on earlier Mac system software and fundamentally different hardware, respectively, before Apple switched to PPC, released the first versions of Mac OS X, and then switched to x86 based hardware.  After all, what isn't broken cannot be fixed, and often "fixing" something that isn't broken will indeed lead to the discovery at the worst imaginable moments that essential functionality is broken or no longer exists.

The affirmative answer to the question should be along the lines of:

1) there are security concerns that you hope to resolve

2) there are software bugs that you hope to resolve

3) there are new features available and you wish to take advantage of them

There is nothing wrong with remaining at a version of a stable and mature operating system that is perhaps getting long in the tooth, and this is especially poignant with older hardware if after upgrading you discover that you have lost something that you needed. The temptation and immediate compulsion to click "update" or "upgrade" as soon as it is available or one receives notice of it is definitely not considered a "best practice," regardless of what most users are doing or even what the software or hardware vendor recommends that you do. Only you can decide, after careful consideration, what is in your best interests, as going backwards sometimes is not an option (as is the case with Apple's iOS operating system).

Comment: I just wanted to add here, hopefully to entice any future readers who may be curious, that there is something very very special and important, for the sake of proving and experiencing history, about the second revision of the B&W PowerMac running Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard and the version of Disk Utility.app that is included with it. Such a machine and system is not only a gateway into the past via its ability to emulate earlier systems, but also an essential tool for those that, for its own sake, wish to build (resurrect) any Macintosh running MacOS Systems 1-9, and/or A/UX.

Comment: I have a OSX 10.5.8 with Intel and cannot upgrade anything with software update. Nor can I update Safari which is refused access to too many sites that use SSL. Apparently Safari can only be updated by upgrading OSX. But still to find out how to do that.